# Concise C++ loop - when does the condition stop being true

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My apologies if it's an ill-formed question. I was reading Bjarne Stroustrup's book and found this way of copying strings. I wrote a similar code for copying arrays.

```
    int arr1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5,};
    int arr2[5] = {9,10,11,12,13};

    int *a = arr1;
    int *b = arr2;

    // I deduce the original example (C++ book) was with strings, and it terminates because of \0
    while (*a++ = *b++) ;
```

My question is, is this code correct? Or it's undefined behavior, because I am not checking the size of arrays? If it's indeed correct, then when exactly does the condition inside `while` evaluate to false?

EDIT: Right. I have printed values at further addresses (beyond the size of the array) and, the values are being copied until `b` points to some 0 in the memory.

Comment: `it's undefined behavior, because I am not checking the size of arrays?` yes, it is undefined behaviour

Comment: Surely bjarne explained in the book that it works with strings because strings are null-terminated. Other arrays are not terminated

Comment: try it with a `0` in the source array. Its not undefined then and you will see when the condition becomes `false`

Comment: `while (*a++ = *b++) ;` evaluates to `false` as soon `*b` evaluated to `0`. The assignment doesn't contribute to that evaluation anyways.

Comment: @IłyaBursov no, there's no _undefined behavior_ with that code snippet.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Isn't there? What happens when `a` becomes `&(arr[5])` and the `while` loop still hasn't exited?

Comment: @NathanPierson hmm, you mean overall order of evaluation? 

Answer (score 2):

`while (*a++ = *b++) ;` works like this:

1. Execute `*a++ = *b++`

   1. Read a memory address from variable `b`
   2. Read an int from that address
   3. Read a memory address from variable `a`
   4. Write the int to that address
   5. That int is the answer
   6. Increment variable `a` by the number of bytes in an int
   7. Increment variable `b` by the number of bytes in an int
2. If the answer is 0, stop the loop
3. Do nothing
4. Go back to step 1.

So you can see it keeps copying until the last thing it copied was a 0.

Since there's no 0 in your array `arr2`, it keeps reading the memory addresses after the end of `arr2`, and writing the memory addresses after the end of `arr1` until it coincidentally finds a 0. That's undefined behaviour.